# Woocommerce Order Export CSV Amendment to code

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce, export, export-to-csv

and a huge thank you to everyone who looks at this in advance from me..

I had some custom code made many moons ago which allowed us to create a new field in a CSV export file, generated by the Woocommerce CSV order export plugin. The field was based on a few rules to export a column called "tax".

It had much more complicated code setup surrounding procedures with Brexit and how we import tax data into Sage 50.

HOWEVER, I have amended the code but I don't really know PHP well. Essentially, I can see the code is trying to set a variable called "tax_code".

WHAT I NEED, is that if field 'shipping_country' equals "GB", then variable "tax_code" should be set in the export to "T1" OTHERWISE, "tax_code" should be "T0".

A snippet of the code is below and I'm pretty sure, if not hopeful, I don't need loads of code rewritten for me, I just need this amended correctly as and IF ELSE statement.

Is there anyone out there to help - much appreciated.

Regards Craig

```
$tax_code = "";
if (!in_array($order->shipping_country = "GB")) {
    $tax_code = "T1";
}
else {
                $tax_code = "T0";               
}

$order_data['tax'] = $tax_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the statement is doing the opposite to what you want it to do.

The clause `!in_array($order->shipping_country = "GB"))` means "not in_array" i.e. evaluates to `FALSE`. So for GB the `else` will set the tax_code.

You want to set the parameter `$tax_code` to T1 if that clause evaluates to TRUE.

If you have been getting the wrong outcome, try removing the exclamation mark so that the clause says `in_array($order->shipping_country = "GB"))` i.e shipping_country is GB, and you should then see the `$tax_code` parameter set to T1 as you expect.

Comment: Hi Greenweeds  - thank you for your time, however no luck. I've removed the exclamation mark and the $tax_code parameter is ALWAYS T0. With the exclamation mark left in, the parameter is always T1 regardless of the country code!

Comment: Mmm. To me, that suggests it never finds a case where shipping_country is "GB" ... If you have a way to output the values from the array, perhaps print the value of shipping_country to your screen so you can see it, to make sure you are grabbing what you think you are grabbing. 

Also, maybe humor me as my PHP is very rusty. What if you use 
`if (in_array($order->shipping_country, "GB"))` 

See these examples: https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/WC_Shipping/instance/php-wc_shipping-instance-method-examples.html